# How to build an AppKit table view using SwiftUI?

Tags: macos, nstableview, swiftui, appkit

We have got a lot of tutorials for iOS with code like this:

```
List(items) { item in
  NavigationLink(destination: ItemView(item: item)) {
    ItemRow(item: item)
  }
}
```

On macOS however, this code results in a list of disabled table cell views.

So how do we build something like `NSTableView` using SwiftUI?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to use `NavigationLink`, you’ll need to be in a `NavigationView` context.
Wrapping your current view hierarchy in a `NavigationView` should fix your issue.

```
NavigationView {
    List(items) { item in
      NavigationLink(destination: ItemView(item: item)) {
        ItemRow(item: item)
      }
    } 
}
```